# Boolean check if a file has been opened in the past hour

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a crontab that checks inside some specified directory and checks if the files are more than an hour old.

```
!#/bin/bash
for F in /My/Path/*.txt;do
    if [ ***TEST IF FILE WAS OPENED IN THE PAST HOUR *** ] 
        then 
          echo "$F"
        fi
    done
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Just use find `find /My/Path/ -name '*.txt' -mmin +30`

Comment: Keep in mind this information may not be available at all in some cases (e.g. if the file system is mounted with noatime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more rigorous approach using `GNU date`, which has an option `-r`

```
-r, --reference=FILE
       display the last modification time of FILE
```

Using the above, incorporating in your script

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /My/Path/*.txt ; do
    if (( (($(date +%s) - $(date -r "$filename" +%s))/60) <= 60 )); then
        echo "$filename"
    fi
done
```

The logic is straight-forward, we are getting the file modification time in minutes by subtracting the file's modification `EPOCH` with the current time. If the file is modified within `60 minutes`, the particular file is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple find

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -newermt "1 hours ago"
```

Any files accessed / modified within the past hour will print to stdout. No need to loop and print.

```
#/bin/bash
OLD_FILES=$(find /path/to/directory -type f -newermt "1 hours ago")
if [[ -n $OLD_FILES ]]; then
    echo "$OLD_FILES" 
else 
    echo "No old files found in dir"
fi
```

You can always pipe the results to a log file if you're trying to compile a list as well

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -newermt "1 hours ago" >> $yourLogFile
```